# How to Link Group Option Combo Box to Database then for Source

Tags: java, database, simulation, anylogic

I have combo box in simulation **experiment screen** as below :

[image]

There are 3 choices, Group 1, Group 2, and Group 3. I have make variables for this. but, how to make this variables links to database reference?

[image]

Database will be used for source Arrival table in database. I hope if I choice in experiment screen Group 1, then Group 1 table will be source data. Thanks you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it directly as you hope. But you could simply use an "if-else" statement: if the user chose "Group 1", load from the `table_group1` and so on. Easiest approach.

Anything fancier will be a lot more complicated and probably not worth it :)

Comment: where should I use an "if-else" statement? in source properties?

Comment: One idea, easy and dirty: Use 3 source blocks (each using 1 of the tables). But block the 2 that are not selected using a Hold block.